# PostAsJsonAsync And Anonymous Types - 404 Not Found Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've been unsuccessfully trying to get this working.

I'm using AttributeRouting on the API and I have this method defined on my WebAPI:

```
    [POST("update"), JsonExceptionFilter]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostUpdate([FromJson] long id, DateTime oriDt, string notes, int score)
```

When I try to call this with the following code:

```
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(CreateAuthorizingHandler(AuthorizationState)))
        {
            var args = new { id, oriDt, notes, score };

            var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", id.ToString()));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("oriDt", oriDt.ToString(_dateService.DefaultDateFormatStringWithTime)));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("notes ", notes));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("score ", score.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

            var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(ApiRootUrl + "update", postData).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().Result;
                return data;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

The response is always `404 - not found`.  What am I missing here?  I've tried using an anonymous object called `args` in the code with the same issue.

I've also tried it with and witout the `[FromJson]` attribute as well with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `[FromJson]`. With that, you have this action method.

`public HttpResponseMessage PostUpdate(long id, DateTime oriDt,
                                           string notes, int score)`

If you POST to the URI below, it will work.

/update/123?oridt=somedate&notes=somenote&score=89

If you want to use request body to POST the fields (as you are doing with the client code), declare a class containing properties with name same as the field in request body.

```
public class MyDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OriDt { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the action method like this.

`public HttpResponseMessage PostUpdate(MyDto dto)`